# Overload operator== and operator!= - are there downsides to implement one via another?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, operator-overloading

```
class classN
{
public:
bool operator== (const classN &o) const {//some logic here};
bool operator!= (const classN &o) const {return !(*this == o);};
};
```

I see this as the best way to write overloads of operator== and operator!=, as I need to change code only once. however, I've seen in different projects people writing actual code in both overloads. As I mention, I feel it's quite a big downside that if logic will be changed it should be changed in two places, with can leads to a bugs when you will forget to make similar change in other overload. But maybe there are some downsides I'm not aware of writing the way I've shown now, using `return !(*this == o);` ? Like calling to a operator== overload inside operator!= being too expensive, so it makes sense to write actual code with comparison of the class fields? Or something else?

Comment: There are no downsides. Additionally: once you upgrade your C++ compiler to one that supports the current C++ standard you won't even have to write it yourself, the compiler will write it for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: DRY says this is the way to do it.  You can also do the same thing with the other comparison operators.  See the section *Comparison operators* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4342498